# Fail to inject @Value in tests with Spring, Spock & Groovy

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spock

I have problems with injection `@Value('${mybean.secret}')` property into my bean during tests in Spock with Spring Boot & Groovy.

I have a very simple test class `MyBeanTest`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [
    MyAppConfig
])
@PropertySource([
    "classpath:context/default-properties.yml"
])
class MyBeanTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean

    def "should populate properties "() {
        expect:
            myBean.secretProperty == "iCantTellYou"
    }
}
```

And `MyAppConfig.groovy` as this:

```
@Configuration
class MyAppConfig {

    @Bean
    MyBean credential(@Value('${mybean.secret}') String secret) {
        return new MyBean(secret)
    }
}
```

When I run tests the `value` that is injected into `secret` is simply `${mybean.secret}`.
**The real value is not injected from `properties` file** I enclose on test specification.

I'm using single-quote on `@Value` because of Groovy. Double `quote` with `$` sign makes it being processed by groovy GString mechanism.

**However, the problem doesn't occur on regular application run.**

If I start application and put the breakpoint on the `MyAppConfig#credential` method the `secret` value is correctly read from the properties file, which are configured as follow:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(["classpath:context/default-properties.yml"])
class PropertiesConfig {
}
```

When I specify property from hand like this:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = [
    "mybean.secret=xyz"
])
class MyBeanTest extends Specification {
```

It works. The property is read. But it's not my goal, cause there's much more properties in the project and it would become cumbersone to define them everywhere from hand.

---

Can you spot the problem I am missing in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The missing puzzle was YamlPropertySourceFactory.

```
public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String name, EncodedResource encodedResource) 
      throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());

        Properties properties = factory.getObject();

        return new PropertiesPropertySource(encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(), properties);
    }
}
```

I was using `yml` properties files with nested properties:

```
mybean:
  secret: xyz
```

And Spring was not loading them correctly.

I had to update `@PropertySource` annotation as well as follow:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(
    value = ["classpath:context/default-properties.yml"],
  factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class
)
class PropertiesConfig {
}
```

Now it works like a charm .

I learned this on Baeldung website => https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource